# Android abstract class error for method

Tags: android, class, manifest, abstract

So I followed a simple tutorial line by line but am getting the error message:
Class stepcounter must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onAccuracyChanged(sensor, int) in sensorevent listener.

Edit://I changed the public class to public abstract class but I attempted to add it to the manifest but wasn't accepted as it wasn't a concrete class so didn't open on a button click to the activity, the app crashed.

Here is the code:

```
public class StepCounter extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView textView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
    private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stepcounter);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView47);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
                getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        float[] values = event.values;
        int value = -1;

        if (values.length > 0) {
            value = (int) values[0];
        }

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
            // For test only. Only allowed value is 1.0 i.e. for step taken
            textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor,

                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,

                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing SensorEventListener, thatswhy you have to provide an implementation for onAccuracyChanged(sensor, int):

```
 @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){}
```

If you make your class abstract, you won't be able to instantiate it.

Check:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1):

When you implement SensorEventListener, you need to implement the methods that it comes with, because it's an [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Add the method onAccuraryChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) in order to fix the problem.

Comment: What do i put in onAccuraryChanged()

Comment: Whatever you want the program to do when the accuracy of the sensor changes. If you don't want to do anything, you can leave it blank but you still need to inherit the method (write it out).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class, that is why it cannot be created from manifest.

Do the other thing the compiler suggested you: implement method onAccuracyChanged.

Comment: What do i put in onAccuraryChanged()

Comment: I added protected void onAccuracyChanged(){
        super.onAccuracyChanged();
    } but says cannot resolve method

Comment: You can leave it empty. The method is from an interface so there is no `super` to be called.

Comment: Add @Override upon the method

Comment: You also need to remove `abstract` from the class again.

Comment: i removed abstract added override and override gives me error.

Comment: You need to implement it properly, the whole thing would be public abstract void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor, int accuracy)

Comment: Read the error. `onAccurancyChanged` needs parameters. I am sure the error suggests what parameters that should be.

Comment: Yeah sorry missed that -___-